# How do I save file to current location during FOR recursion

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg

I have a batch script to run ffmpeg on files recursively.  Currently the script saves all the new files to a newly created directory named Output. Instead, I would like to save the new files in the same location as the original files.  I thought I would use an environmental variable showing the current directory being traversed to during recursion but I can't find it.

```
SET /P i=Enter the file extension
md output
For /R %%a IN (*.%i%) DO ffmpeg -i "%%a" -c:v libx264 -crf 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p "output/%%~na.mp4"
```

The script works fine saving the file as the same filename with a new extension but places the file in the new "output" folder. I tried setting a new variable with %cd% within the FOR loop but that didn't work.

Comment: Change `"output/%%~na.mp4"` to `"%%~dpna.mp4"`...

Answer (score 1):

```
... "%%~dpna.mp4"
```

should do this.

Note that in the Windows world, `\` is a directory-separator and `/` is a switch-indicator. Windows often, but not always, makes the translation. Best to use the correct form.

Metavariable modifiers are documented under `for /?` from the prompt. They are `d` for `drive`, `p` for `path`, `n` for `name` and `x` for extension. `z` will give you *size*, `s` *shortname*, `t` *datestamp*, `a` *attribute* and `f` will yield the fully-qualified filename within limits). Note that the `path` resulting wil contain both leading and trailing `\` but not `\\`.